# Multi-Line TableView Cell with Text Formatting

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, uitextview

[image]

**Scenario**
I have a JSON feed where I get all this information about places in a city. The design looks like this (see attached image).

The design wants **bolded text**, **URL text**, **different font size text**. Sometimes the URL might not exist in the JSON feed.

**Question**
Which option is the best way to lay this out in a TableViewCell?

I'm thinking Option 3 is the easiest as I read that in Swift 4 you can use the new string literals. Concat all the strings with line breaks and then place them in a UITextView. But I don't think it supports formatted text.

Looking for feedback please

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:** Based on the research below I figured out that you can solve this by using:

```
- NSAttributedStringKey
- NSAttributedString
- NSMutableAttributedString
```

**First Step**
I created a private function called `generateEntry` that returns an `NSMutableAttributedString`

```
private func generateEntry(bType: String, bTitle:String, bDescription:String, bUrl: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
    // -- passed in parameters
    let bookmarkType:String = bType
    let bookmarkTitle:String = bTitle
    let bookmarkDesc: String = bDescription
    let bookmarkUrl: String = bUrl
    // -- type
    // Step 1 - you need to create the attribute for the string you want to change. Size, color, kern effect
    // Step 2 - then you create a NSAttributedString and apply the attributes from the previous line
    let bTypeAttribute = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 14), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, NSAttributedStringKey.kern: NSNumber(value: 0.5)]
    let test: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: bookmarkType.uppercased() + ": ", attributes: bTypeAttribute as Any as? [NSAttributedStringKey : Any])

    // -- title
    let bTitleAttribute = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Arial-Bold", size: 18), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
    let testb: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: bookmarkTitle, attributes: bTitleAttribute as Any as? [NSAttributedStringKey : Any])

    // -- description
    let bDescriptionAttribute = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
    let testc: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: ": " + bookmarkDesc, attributes: bDescriptionAttribute as Any as? [NSAttributedStringKey : Any])

    // -- url
    let bURLAttribute = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Arial-Italic", size: 18), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
    let testd: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: bookmarkUrl, attributes: bURLAttribute as Any as? [NSAttributedStringKey : Any])

    // combine the strings
    let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
        mutableAttributedString.append(test)
        mutableAttributedString.append(testb)
        mutableAttributedString.append(testc)
        mutableAttributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n"))
        mutableAttributedString.append(testd)

    return mutableAttributedString
}
```

**Step 2**
Then within my tableViewCell I can use this private method to generate the `NSMutableAttributedString` and apply it to my custom tableViewCell. But instead of using `cell.descriptionLabel.text` you need to make sure to use `attributedText`

```
let testText = generateEntry(bType: "Type", bTitle: "PLACE", bDescription: "A description...", bUrl: "URL")
cell.descriptionLabel?.attributedText = testText
```